# Creating nested dictionaries from parent-child relationship table

Tags: python, json, dictionary, nested, nested-loops

My goal is to build a JSON file that represents the hierarchy of entries that I have in an excel file. In the Excel file, each row has a column that specifies the code of the parent element as well as its own code and a description of the entry (irrelevant).

```
parent  code  description
  A      A1    lorem ipsum
  B      B1    lorem ipsum
  C      C1    lorem ipsum
  A      A2    lorem ipsum
  B1     B11   lorem ipsum
  A2     A21   lorem ipsum
  B11    B112  lorem ipsum
          B    lorem ipsum
  ...
```

How can I programmatically create a JSON output that would look like this in the case of this example

```
tree = [
  {
    "code": "A",
    "description": "Lorem Ipsum",
    "childs": [
      {
        "code": "A1",
        "description": "Lorem Ipsum"
      },
      {
        "code": "A2",
        "description": "Lorem Ipsum",
        "childs": [
           {
             "code": "A21",
             "description": Lorem Ipsum"
           }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "code": "B",
    "description": "Lorem Ipsum",
    "childs": [
      {
        "code": "B1",
        "description": Lorem Ipsum",
        "childs": [
           {
             "code": "B11",
             "description": Lorem Ipsum",
             "childs": [...]
           }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  ...
]
```

You get the point...

I have tried a few different approaches but I can't wrap my head around the nested architecture of the final result. Note that the amount of layers varies from entry to entry.

Any tips?

Comment: Welcome to SO. This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.  Invest some time with [the Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) practicing the examples. It will give you an idea of the tools Python offers to help you solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are working with excel, I will assume your dataset is not too big, so I propose to do the following in excel before reading the file in python:

1. Use `VLOOKUP` recursively in successive columns (until the maximum hierarchical level) and then concatenate and remove duplicates, so you will have something like:

   ```
   parent childs texts    
   A      A2;A21 lorem;lorem2;lorem21
   B      B2;B11 lorem;lorem2;lorem11
   ...
   ```
2. If you need to add in your json A2 as a root, the dataset created the with the previous step will be enough, otherwise you will need to remove all rows where `code` appears in `parent` (easily done with `VLOOKUP` also)

Once you have it, you just need to load it in python and go row by row creating the json.